# Partial match on integer field in LINQ query

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I can get partial matches on string fields with a query like this:

```
employees = context.Employees
    .Where(ee => ee.LastName.Contains(text))
    .ToList();
```

Is there any way to do the same for integer fields?  I tried converting to a string on the fly but no luck:

```
employees = context.Employees
    .Where(ee => ee.EmployeeID.ToString().Contains(text))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: What does it even mean to do that for a numeric field? Why would you want to match "employees with 43 as part of their ID"? That suggests you're really thinking of the ID as a *text* field rather than either a numeric value or just an ID.

Comment: Perhaps he's using this for an autocomplete.  For database efficiency reasons, the ID is best kept as an int as opposed to a varchar.

Comment: Maybe he's testing Benford's Law? :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet - I didn't say it was a good idea, just asked if it could be done? ;)  As for your example, yes that is it exactly.  They want to be able to partially match an ID field, which is an integer in both the database and the employee class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well given that this is hypothetical, if EF doesn't support it directly, just force it to happen in-process:

```
employees = context.Employees
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(ee => ee.EmployeeID.ToString().Contains(text))
    .ToList();
```

Given that it's already a bad idea, pulling all the employee data isn't so much worse ;)

Comment: I will certainly try and talk them out of it, but good to know I have a fallback if forced.  I can always remind them how bad an idea it was if (when?) it becomes a performance issue.

Comment: @Sean: Let me know if you need any help persuading them. Basically it sounds like they should probably have a separate fields. IDs should *only* be use for identification. They should almost always just be treated as values which are equal to or different from each other.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a very good idea at all if you need to search like this you might as well have the searched column as a string. Otherwise what you are doing here is a table scan, regardless of your field is indexed.
By doing so, as your table grows, the table scan will become more expensive.